# Calculation custom image features

Tags: keras

I would like some guidance please.

I want to add a layer that takes an image, processes it in some way outside of the framework and returns a single float as an answer. So inputs: ([images]) and outputs: ([float32 features]).

Lambda functions is something that I see people suggesting but not sure.

Any suggestions or guides that I can use?

Comment: To answer this we need to know what kind of processing you want to apply.  That being said, you are likely to have two choices: (1) if the processing can be implemented by tensor operations, then Lambda layer can be used; (2) alternatively, you may want to write your own data generator that applies the process to image inputs before feeding into keras model.

Comment: I want to assign a single float to each image, rather than doing pre-processing on the image. For example finding the number of corners or some angle per image.

Based on your answer it looks like the data generator might be the way to go.